# delete/select hierarchy data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, hierarchy, postgresql-9.4

I have table `comment`, and I want to delete by input `id` and also delete all child,

below two query both not delete all hierarchy data, only delete self and one child row ...

is there anything wrong when select recursive in `with` closure?

comment

```
id | parent_comment_id
1  | 
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  |
```

query 1

```
WITH RECURSIVE coH AS (
  SELECT co.id,
    co.id AS rootId
    FROM comment co

  UNION ALL

  SELECT coChild.id,
    coChild.parent_comment_id as parentCommentId
    FROM comment coChild
    JOIN coH coP ON coP.id = coChild.parent_comment_id
)
DELETE FROM comment WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM coH WHERE rootId = $1
)
```

query 2

```
DELETE FROM comment WHERE id IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE coH AS (
    SELECT co.id,
      co.id AS rootId
      FROM comment co

    UNION ALL

    SELECT coChild.id,
      coChild.parent_comment_id as parentCommentId
      FROM comment coChild
      JOIN coH coP ON coP.id = coChild.parent_comment_id
  )

  SELECT id FROM coH WHERE rootId = $1
)
```

**UPDATE**

```
var dbQuery = `DELETE FROM comment WHERE id IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE coH (id, parentCommentId, rootId) AS (
    SELECT co.id,
      co.parent_comment_id as parentCommentId,
      co.id AS rootId
      FROM comment co

    UNION ALL

    SELECT coChild.id,
      coChild.parent_comment_id as parentCommentId,
      coP.rootId
      FROM comment coChild
      JOIN coH coP ON coP.id = coChild.parent_comment_id
  )

  SELECT id FROM coH WHERE rootId = $1
)`;
```

Comment: Your queries seem correct, but deletion in the wrong order may cause foreign key violations. You can solve this by not having a foreign key (not recommended!) or by having your foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE, or having it DEFERRABLE.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10381384/5593189 I update in my question, it works to delete all, but I don't know why? what is `coH (id, parentCommentId, rootId)` brace for? and in first part select in with why need to make `co.parent_comment_id as parentCommentId` ?

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I didn't set foreign key in comment table. can I set `comment.parent_comment_id` fk `comment.id` ? if the column could be null still can set foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, place the parameter in the initial query of recursive with:

```
with recursive cbase as (
    select 1 as id -- select $1 as id

    union all

    select child.id
    from comment as child
    join cbase on cbase.id = child.parent_comment_id
)
delete from comment 
where id in (select * from cbase)
returning id;

 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)

DELETE 3
```

Comment: thanks for reply,  and example code!  `select 1 as id` or` select $1 as id`  ?  I still want to know why my query not work, what's different between my original query and update query make it work  ?

Comment: Your query does not work well because it eliminates some rows in the where clause. With this condition you'll always get no more than two rows. `select 1 ...` is only an example to test the query, you should use `select $1...` of course.

Comment: I get error `operator does not exist: text = integer`  ... `JOIN co ON co.id = child.parent_comment_id`  ??

Comment: var dbQuery = `
              WITH RECURSIVE co AS (
                SELECT $1 AS id

                UNION ALL

                SELECT child.id
                FROM comment AS child
                JOIN co ON co.id = child.parent_comment_id
              )
              DELETE FROM comment 
              WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM co)
              RETURNING id`;

Comment: I change the first select in with closure and it work..    `
              WITH RECURSIVE co AS (
                SELECT co.id AS id
                  FROM comment co
                  WHERE id = $1

                UNION ALL

                SELECT child.id
                FROM comment AS child
                JOIN co ON co.id = child.parent_comment_id
              )
              DELETE FROM comment 
              WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM co)
              RETURNING id;`

Comment: Probably the value of the parameter was written as text. In the case cast the value to integer `select $1::int ...`.

Comment: but I create table like ` CREATE TABLE comment
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  parent_comment_id integer,  ...`